# How do I filter entries in CP by Entry Type?

Tags: control-panel, search, entry-type

I have an entry type called `industry` and am trying to use this search syntax in the CP to filter my entries by that type:

`type:"industry"`

I am getting no results whatsoever. How do I filter entries in CP by Entry Type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a great plugin that allows you to add columns Craft doesn't initially provide.  This plugin also allows you to filter by those, like Entry Type.

https://github.com/mmikkel/DashCols-Craft/

Comment: I'm the developer of DashCols – please note that following the [announcement of Craft 2.5](http://buildwithcraft.com/beta), DashCols has been retired (as the 2.5 release will have most of DashCols functionality in core). Unfortunately though, 2.5 won't actually enable you to sort on Entry Type, even if you add it as a column.

Comment: Just found this: https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/entry-type-sources, which appears to do exactly what the OP is asking for. Haven't tested it with 2.5, so a word of caution as that update makes some significant changes to Element Index related APIs.